# SFINAE for detecting existence of non-member template function

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

**TL;DR** I want to write a template function `Process(T value)` that behaves differently for different values depending on the existence of a non-member function `CreateProcessor<T>()`. What can I do for that?

I have a problem with SFINAE. Suppose we need to support function `CreateProcessor` that returns an implementation of interface `IProcessor<T>` for some type type `T`.

In C++ we can't create several overloads of a function that differ only in return type, so we have to make function `CreateProcessor` also be template function parametrized by `T`.

Now suppose that we want to write a template function `Process<T>(T value)` that works differently depending on existence of `CreateProcessor<T>()`, namely it should process `value` using the processor in case `CreateProcessor<T>()` is implemented, otherwise it should result in error.

I attempted to write the following code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

// A workaround for void_t as described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t.
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

// An interface for a processor that receives a value of specific type.
template<class T>
class IProcessor {
public:
    virtual void process(T value) = 0;
};

// A processor for int.
class IntProcessor : public IProcessor<int> {
public:
    virtual void process(int value) override {
        printf("IntProcessor::process is called for value = %d\n", value);
    }
};

// Template prototype.
template<class T> 
IProcessor<T>* CreateProcessor();

// Template specialization for int.
template<>
IProcessor<int>* CreateProcessor() {
    return new IntProcessor();
}

// Detector of CreateProcessor.
template<class, class=void>
struct CreateProcessorImplemented : std::false_type { };

template<class T>
struct CreateProcessorImplemented<T, void_t<decltype(CreateProcessor<T>())>> : std::true_type { };


// Specializations depending on existence of CreateProcessor.
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<CreateProcessorImplemented<T>::value, void>::type Process(T value) {
    IProcessor<T>* processor = CreateProcessor<T>();
    processor->process(value);
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!CreateProcessorImplemented<T>::value, void>::type Process(T value) {
    printf("Processor for requested typename is unavailable\n");
}


int main() {
    Process(42);
    Process("abc");

// static_assert(!CreateProcessorImplemented<char const*>::value, ":(");
/* This static_assert fails with an error:
 * code.cpp:56:5: error: static assertion failed: :(
 *      static_assert(!CreateProcessorImplemented<char const*>::value, ":(");
 */
}
```

Though this results in linkage error:

```
/tmp/ccTQRc9N.o:code.cpp:function std::enable_if<CreateProcessorImplemented<char const*, void>::value, void>::type Process<char const*>(char const*): error: undefined reference to 'IProcessor<char const*>* CreateProcessor<char const*>()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My idea is that when we resolve `CreateProcessorImplemented<char const*>`, `decltype(CreateProcessor<const char*>())` doesn't fail because there is a template prototype `IProcessor<T> CreateProcessor()` and compiler considers the decltype to be equal to `IProcessor<T>` that is somehow logical but not what I need.

Comment: `CreateProcessorImplemented` always derives from `std::true_type` because a function doesn't need to have an implementation for `decltype` to tell you the return type (see `std::declval`).

Comment: @Simple, That makes sence. I believe there is no way to check if function has an implementation during the compile-time since it requires a knowledge from linker, right?

Comment: An alternative is in the answer from @WojciechFrohmberg. You use a `struct` with a static member function instead of a non-member function. You *can* detect if there is no static member function due to the `struct` not being specialised. It's basically a type trait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to make it work is to use wrapper struct to function `CreateProcessor` like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

// A workaround for void_t as described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t.
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

// An interface for a processor that receives a value of specific type.
template<class T>
class IProcessor {
public:
    virtual void process(T value) = 0;
};

// A processor for int.
class IntProcessor : public IProcessor<int> {
public:
    virtual void process(int value) override {
        printf("IntProcessor::process is called for value = %d\n", value);
    }
};

// Template prototype.
template<class T>
struct ProcessorCreator: std::false_type { 
   static IProcessor<T>* CreateProcessor();
};

// Template specialization for int.
template<>
struct ProcessorCreator<int>: std::true_type {
static IProcessor<int>* CreateProcessor() {
    return new IntProcessor();
}
};

// Detector of CreateProcessor.
template<class, class=void>
struct CreateProcessorImplemented : std::false_type { };

template<class T>
struct CreateProcessorImplemented<T, typename std::enable_if<ProcessorCreator<T>::value>::type > : std::true_type { };


// Specializations depending on existence of CreateProcessor.
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<CreateProcessorImplemented<T>::value, void>::type Process(T value) {
    IProcessor<T>* processor = ProcessorCreator<T>::CreateProcessor();
    processor->process(value);
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!CreateProcessorImplemented<T>::value, void>::type Process(T value) {
    printf("Processor for requested typename is unavailable\n");
}


int main() {
    Process(42);
    Process("abc");

// static_assert(!CreateProcessorImplemented<char const*>::value, ":(");
/* This static_assert fails with an error:
 * code.cpp:56:5: error: static assertion failed: :(
 *      static_assert(!CreateProcessorImplemented<char const*>::value, ":(");
 */
}
```

Alternatively you could remove template declaration and pass the IProcessor template parameter type using function overloadings -- by creating dummy argument:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

// A workaround for void_t as described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t.
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

// An interface for a processor that receives a value of specific type.
template<class T>
class IProcessor {
public:
    virtual void process(T value) = 0;
};

// A processor for int.
class IntProcessor : public IProcessor<int> {
public:
    virtual void process(int value) override {
        printf("IntProcessor::process is called for value = %d\n", value);
    }
};


IProcessor<int>* CreateProcessor(const int&) {
    return new IntProcessor();
}

// Detector of CreateProcessor.
template<class, class=void>
struct CreateProcessorImplemented : std::false_type { };

template<class T>
struct CreateProcessorImplemented<T, void_t<decltype(CreateProcessor(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type { };


// Specializations depending on existence of CreateProcessor.
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<CreateProcessorImplemented<T>::value, void>::type Process(T value) {
    IProcessor<T>* processor = CreateProcessor(value);
    processor->process(value);
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!CreateProcessorImplemented<T>::value, void>::type Process(T value) {
    printf("Processor for requested typename is unavailable\n");
}


int main() {
    Process(42);
    Process("abc");

// static_assert(!CreateProcessorImplemented<char const*>::value, ":(");
/* This static_assert fails with an error:
 * code.cpp:56:5: error: static assertion failed: :(
 *      static_assert(!CreateProcessorImplemented<char const*>::value, ":(");
 */
}
```