# C++ enable_if is_member_function_pointer call depending on existence of member function

Tags: c++, member, enable-if

after having scrawled through several threads such as this one

[SFINAE for detecting existence of non-member template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939855/sfinae-for-detecting-existence-of-non-member-template-function)

without finding a solution, I am posting my question here. For a tiny logger class I want to surveil the amount of data logged using the << operator. When, for instance, a string is passe or an array having the .size() member function, I want to add size() number of bytes to that amount, sizeof(...) otherwise.

How can I (using VS 2010, which has very sparse C++11 support) make use of std::enable_if and std::is_member_function_pointer to reach my goal? How can I, for instance, define a function getSize() that operates as wanted?

The code below indicates what I want, but I guess I cannot define getSize twice...

Thanks a lot for help!

```
template<typename T,
typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::size)>::value> 
>
size_t getSize(const T &p_rObj)
{
    return p_rObj.size();
}

template<typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::size)>::value>
>
size_t getSize(const T &p_rObj)
{
    return sizeof(p_rObj);
}
```

Addendumg/Edit: The following either does not work with VS 2010, which then expects every call of getSize(...) to have two parameters...

```
template<typename T> 
size_t getSize(std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::size)>::value>, const T &p_rObj)
{
    return p_rObj.size();
}

template<typename T>
size_t getSize(std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::size)>::value>, const T &p_rObj)
{
    return sizeof(p_rObj);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I guess I found the solution myself: Using the std::enable_if as a function parameter. However, Herb Sutter strongly discrecommends this, an I am looking forward to getting alternative suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define twice

```
template<typename T, typename> size_t getSize(const T &p_rObj);
```

And you forget `::type`
and your traits is not SFINAE compatible

The traits could be implemented:

```
template <typename T> auto has_size_impl(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().size(), std::true_type{});
template <typename T> auto has_size_impl(...) -> std::false_type;

template <typename T>
using has_size = decltype(has_size_impl<T>(0));
```

You have to use `std::enable_if` in return type, template argument or regular argument:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_size<T>::value, std::size_t>::type
getSize(const T &p_rObj);
```

or

```
template<typename T, 
typename std::enable_if<has_size<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
std::size_t getSize(const T &p_rObj);
```

or

```
template<typename T>
std::size_t getSize(const T &p_rObj,
                    typename std::enable_if<has_size<T>::value>::type* = nullptr);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a84a8de4d1069f0)

Comment: Yes, I know I defined it twice (see my own comment above). And how do you suggest returning either size() or sizeof()? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I mean changing *default argument* doesn't count as **new** function.

Comment: No has_size here... and no ::type (not part of the VS 2010 TR1 implementation)

Comment: As you might notice, there is a Demo link. traits added in answer anyway.

Comment: Even if asked two years ago: Thanks for the reply and the demo. Meanwhile, VS 2010 is long past and it did not work with your code. Starting with 2015, things are fine and I thank you for getting back to this -- anyway C++17 comes in action now! Checked your answer as correct!